# Why changing the focus programatically on secured text box lets last character appear

Tags: uitextfield, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder, ios11, xcode9-beta

Lets say I have a secured textfield and I am trying to change the focus to some other textfield on *UIControlEventEditingChanged* by calling *BecomeFirstResponder* or *ResignFirstResponder* then the last character is still visible

[image: Snapshot]

I am changing the focus to second text box when it reaches three characters but you can see third character is still visible even after the focus is on next textfield and one more character was also typed in.

if you non-programatically i.e manually change the focus from secured textfield to some other textfield then this problem is not happening.

Has anybody discovered any workaround to fix the issue ?

Please click [here](https://github.com/Duraiamuthan/iOS11SecuredTextFieldIssue) to go to a sample project which demonstrates this problem

P.S

I have already reported the issue in Apple Bug Reporter